# Trying to debug phpunit unit test on cli using xdebug fails

Tags: php, debugging, phpunit, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm which is configured to use xDebug (I can debug via the web browser just fine)

I run the debugger in PHPStorm which has the idekey of 11854 and I'm trying to debug a unit test, and I've set the breakpoints properly

so I executed this command through the cli:

```
phpunit -d xdebug.profiler_enable=on -d xdebug.idekey=11854 --filter testFunction s_function/sFunctionTest.php
```

Nonetheless, it wouldn't debug at the breakpoint accordingly...

when I tried executing this in the test script:

```
error_log(ini_get('xdebug.profiler_enable'));
error_log(ini_get('xdebug.idekey'));
```

it would reveal that xdebug.profiler_enable is 0 and xdebug.idekey is just my username.

What did I do wrong and how can I get xdebug to work on phpunit through the cli

Comment: If you are able to debug normal scripts in **CLI mode** in PhpStorm .. then do the same but with PHPUnit: create Run/Debug Configuration of PHPUnit type, fill all required fields so you can run it in PHPUnit .. and instead of "Run" use "Debug" button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just setting arguments to phpunit, not to PHP. The following should do what you want:

```
php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=on -d xdebug.idekey=11854 `which phpunit` --filter testFunction s_function/sFunctionTest.php
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot on what's the expected output after running this command?

Comment: you should explain what and why parameters are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

The [xdebug docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) give a solution that looks simpler...

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name"
php myscript.php
```

Once that variable is set, you can run your scripts from the command line as normal (for that SSH session) and PHP will use this configuration.

Also of note:

> You can also configure the xdebug.remote_host, xdebug.remote_port,
>   xdebug.remote_mode and xdebug.remote_handler in this same environment
>   variable as long as you separate the values by a space

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu to debug CLI I found the only way to get it to work was to add the following to your ~/.bashrc file

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG='serverName=localhost'
export XDEBUG_CONFIG='idekey=PHPSTORM'
```

Replace idekey=?? to 11854 in your example.
Be sure to start a new console session so the vars are used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying here a very different setup. I run my applications inside dockers and I have a container very similar to containers running on production. So, to run php with xdebug in my development environment, I had to setup an alias with xdebug params and the PHPStorm variable.

```
$ alias php=`which php`' \
    -d xdebug.idekey=xdbg \
    -d xdebug.remote_enable=1 \
    -d xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 \
    -d xdebug.remote_autostart=1 \
    -d xdebug.remote_port=9000 \
    -d xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1 \
    -d xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp'

$ export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localapp.docker"
```

After this not beautiful trick, I could put breakpoints on PHPStorm and run phpunit from command line.

```
$ php ../../bin/phpunit --verbose
```

All commands above was run inside container. The `localapp.docker` is the address of my container and is hardcoded `/etc/hosts` of host.